# GUI tool to manage services in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, services

Are there any GUI tools to manage the services running on Ubuntu?

Comment: I searched for this today and found this [GuillaumeGomez/systemd-manager](https://github.com/GuillaumeGomez/systemd-manager)

Answer (score 8):

I like [BUM - Boot-Up Manager](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-up-manager-bum-graphical-runlevel-editor.html) :) You can manage the services using BUM. It's not installed by default. Run the following command in the terminal to install it "sudo apt-get install bum"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have always loved rcconf

Install it by

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
```

and then

```
sudo rcconf
```